# Error when cuztomizing Iterable behaviour on Array

Tags: javascript, iterator

I'm learning about cuztomizing the behaviour of an iterable but I've encountered an error. In the first scenario, I am directly working on the array's [Symbol.iterator]. This works fine. If I try to move it to the prototype, unfortunately the code doesn't run. I'm unable to understand the error. Any help with defining a custom iteration behaviour at the prototype level is much appreciated. Thanks

Scenario 1

```
const test = [2,4,6,8,10]

test[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let index = 0;
  return {
    next: () => (
      index === this.length
      ? { done: true }
      : {
        value: this[index++] * 2,
        done: false
      }
    )
  }
}

for (const item of test) console.log(item) - Returns 20 40 60 80 100
```

Scenario 2

```
Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let index = 0;
  return {
    next: () => (
      index === this.length
      ? { done: true }
      : {
        value: this[index++] * 10,
        done: false
      }
    )
  }
}

const test = [2,4,6,8,10]

for (const item of test) console.log(item) - TypeError: release(...).split is not a function
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Code works for me.

Comment: May I ask if you ran it on node or in the browser?